# Xpath - search root with conditions and below root with conditions

Tags: xpath, jcr

I have a structure like this:

```
<sv:a>
 <sv:b sv:name="one"/>
 <sv:b sv:name="two"/>
   <sv:c sv:name="exclude"/>
 <sv:b sv:name="error"/>
<sv:a>
```

I am trying to get all a's and b's but exclude from my search the content of any c.

I have this structure so far for my xpath query

```
//*[not(name()='error') and jcr:contains(*, 'searchInput')]
```

I want to add something to this to essentially say, "do not give me any node named exclude" or maybe a better way to put it is "exclude any node named exclude from the search". I am not sure if I can do that using the path initially used of //* and just filtering a different way.  I know I cannot just say not(name()='exclude') because it is only looking at one level below root and only excludes nodes at that level.

Is there a way to search 1 more level below and exclude certain nodes by their name or search everything in the entire document and exclude those nodes of a particular name?

Im not sure it matters, but I am working the CMS Magnolia and trying to make a site search.  I hit a limitation using jcr sql2 and cannot do what I am trying to do here as far as I have found in researching this.

**EDIT:**

Based on answers and comments, here is what I am looking at now:

```
//*[not(@sv:name='exclude' or @sv:name='error') and jcr:contains(*, 'searchInput)]
```

I still seem to be getting the 'exclude' results so I must either not be registering 'sv:' correctly or missing something in the query needed to exclude some of the results from the search.

Comment: You use `name()`, but could it be that you actually mean `@name`?

Comment: I just checked and it seems that either would work.  Probably @name performs better but I wouldn't know off hand

Comment: They are different things. `name()` gives you the name of the node at hand. You have no nodes named `exclude`. But what you do have is nodes named `b` with an *attribute* called `name` and a value of `"exclude"`. And attributes can you get with `@`.

Comment: I updated the structure of my data to represent something closer to what I have.  I'm not sure why, but I get the same results if I use either @name or name()

Comment: Take `<sv:c sv:name="exclude"/>`, for example. When on that node, `name()` gives you `"sv:c"`, whereas `@name` gives you nothing and `@sv:name` gives you `"exclude"` (provided you have registered the `sv` namespace properly beforehand). — You see the same results with `name()` and `@name` because your test is in a `not()` and never succeeds because it is faulty. Therefore it makes no difference what you put there until you fix that test.

Comment: Reverse check: What does `//*[@sv:name='exclude']` give you? If that does not return anything despite the fact that there is at least one `<sv:c sv:name="exclude"/>` in your input then you have a namespace setup issue.

Comment: it seems that I dont have it registered correctly.  I will work on this now.  Thanks again.

Comment: I assume you have found and fixed your namespace issue?

Comment: I haven't yet.  Shortly after that post I got pulled away to work on something else for work.  I will probably be back at this sometime next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add something to this to essentially say, "do not give me any node named exclude"

That's easy: Nodes (*elements*) named `exclude` can be selected via the `self` axis,
using `*[self::exclude]`. Corollary: An element not named `exclude` is `*[not(self::exclude)]`.

But I think you don't refer to element names. You don't have any `<exclude>` elements in your input.

You actually seem to refer to *attributes*.

```
//*[not(@sv:name = 'error' or @sv:name = 'exclude') and jcr:contains(*, 'searchInput')]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get all a's and b's but exclude from my search the content of any c.

You can't, at least not with pure XPath.  XPath is a language for *selecting* nodes out of an XML tree, not for building new trees that are different.  An XPath expression can either select the `a` or not select the `a`, but it can't give you a *new* `a` element that has only some of the children of the original `a` and not others.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I wonder if there is a way to accomplish what I am doing another way.

Comment: @wondergoat77 to transform one XML structure into another you can use a higher-level language like XSLT or XQuery, but I don't know if there's anything specific to your CMS that would be easier.

Comment: @wondergoat77 As I see it, I don't suspect you want to *build* another output tree; you just want to exclude certain nodes from a search. And that much is absolutely possible with XPath.